# Android game (Llama or Duck) OutOfMemory on setContentView

Tags: java, android, performance

I have made updates to this Llama or Duck game (a recreation of an already-existing game) and the app very inconsistently closes out due to an outOfMemory error. I have made multiple attempts to clear up memory such as using addFlags from Intent and researching different solutions and yet the errors keep coming. By the way, this is one of the two screens (essentially identical) that will be constantly recreated throughout the game as the user is playing. The goal is for the user to select which animal is being shown on the screen, and if correct they will keep playing. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
package com.example.ryan.llamaorduck;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class DuckScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean isLlamaScreen = false; //false because this is the Duck screen
int duck_score;
Intent intent;
int screen; // variable used just for finding the next random screen
int pic; //not currently implemented
SharedPreferences pref; //used for storing score
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Timer timer; //used to change window if time runs out
TimerTask timerTask;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_duck_screen);

    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF",MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=pref.edit();


    duck_score=pref.getInt("tempDuckScore",0);

    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int tempDuckScore = duck_score;
            editor.putInt("tempDuckScore",tempDuckScore);

            timer.cancel();

            //below are my attempts to clear up memory space to make 
            //the app perform better.

            intent = new Intent(DuckScreen.this,GameOver.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };



    timer.schedule(timerTask,2000);
}

// user clicked on the llama button.
//method implementation decides if they are correct and either ends the 
//game or moves them onto the next random page. 

public void llamaClick(View view){
    timer.cancel();
    if (isLlamaScreen){
        Random r = new Random();
        screen = r.nextInt(2);
        if (screen == 1){ //DUCK
            int tempDuckScore = duck_score;
            editor.putInt("tempDuckScore",tempDuckScore);
            intent = new Intent(DuckScreen.this,DuckScreen.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else{
            int tempDuckScore = duck_score;
            editor.putInt("tempDuckScore",tempDuckScore);
            intent = new Intent(DuckScreen.this,LlamaScreen.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }else{
        int tempDuckScore = duck_score;
        editor.putInt("tempDuckScore",tempDuckScore);
        intent = new Intent(DuckScreen.this,GameOver.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}


//user clicked on the button indicating that they think the animal is a
//duck. Same idea as method before, testing other button.

public void duckClick(View view){
    timer.cancel();
    if (!isLlamaScreen){
        Random r = new Random();
        screen = r.nextInt(2);
        if (screen == 1){ //DUCK
            int tempDuckScore = duck_score;
            editor.putInt("tempDuckScore",tempDuckScore);
            intent = new Intent(DuckScreen.this,DuckScreen.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else{
            int tempDuckScore = duck_score;
            editor.putInt("tempDuckScore",tempDuckScore);
            intent = new Intent(DuckScreen.this,LlamaScreen.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }else{
        int tempDuckScore = duck_score;
        editor.putInt("tempDuckScore",tempDuckScore);
        intent = new Intent(DuckScreen.this,GameOver.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public int getDuckScore(){
    return duck_score;
}

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.ryan.llamaorduck.DuckScreen">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:src="@drawable/duck"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/duck"
    />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/duck"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Duck"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="duckClick"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Llama"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="llamaClick"
        />
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ERROR MSG:

```
04-05 11:57:59.451 6438-6438/com.example.ryan.llamaorduck E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 8748016-byte allocation.
04-05 11:57:59.601 6438-6438/com.example.ryan.llamaorduck E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                                at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
                                                                                at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
                                                                                at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                                                                                at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:668)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                at com.example.ryan.llamaorduck.DuckScreen.onCreate(DuckScreen.java:28)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: My bad, it is OutOfMemory

Comment: You need to use an image loading library. Your picture is too large and you didn't scale it down. Look into the Picasso library, for example.

Comment: @Ryan Does your application work fine at startup and then fails after using it for a while?? Or it doesn't start correctly? Because I think you should have memory enough to run your application although you have "big" images lo be loaded

Answer (score 2):

Try setting

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Inside of the `<application>` tag of your manifest; this will launch the application with more memory allocated to the heap.

[Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap).

Note: *Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.*

If you are gettin an OOM, you have  a fundamental issue with your code - this is simply a bandaid.

Comment: Unfortunately errors still come:  Out of memory on a 8748016-byte allocation.

Comment: what is the width / height of `duck.png`?

Comment: Being as the images themselves do not matter to much to me, I changed them and it worked. thank you

Comment: It is my assumption that `duck.png` was something download from the web, and it was something of a 1080p image that you were scaling down to like 100px or so; something way oversized for the use, taking too much of the apps memory to manage; glad that worked. Cheers.